# How to install latest virtualbox-dkms with latest virtualbox on Debian Stable Wheezy

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, debian-wheezy

It is possible to install the latest virtualbox and extension pack on Wheezy using the following:

```
# su sh -c 'echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | su apt-key add -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

If one then tries to install virtualbox-dkms (to prevent virtualbox from failing after a kernel upgrade) it is necessary to uninstall the latest (4.3) version of virtualbox.

The 4.3 virtualbox-dkms in not available in the wheezy backports, which can be added by as an administrator including the following line in /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main

**How can the latest 4.3 virtualbox-dkms be installed with the latest virtualbox on Wheezy?**

Answer (score 3):

You *don't* need to install `virtualbox-dkms`.

You *do* need to install `dkms` package, which is a part of standard Debian repository.

I normally install it before installing VirtualBox, but the order might not matter:

```
$ sudo aptitude install dkms
$ sudo aptitude install virtualbox-4.3
```

During kernel updates you will see that DKMS updates VirtualBox modules automatically.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads:

> Note: Ubuntu/Debian users might want to install the dkms package to
>   ensure that the VirtualBox host kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt
>   and vboxnetadp) are properly updated if the linux kernel version
>   changes during the next apt-get upgrade. For Debian it is available in
>   Lenny backports and in the normal repository for Squeeze and later.

Comment: With Focal Fossa (20.04), `virtualbox-dkms` is a dependency of the main `virtualbox` package ; I suspect this was the case earlier as well, but probably won't bother going back in time to check it )

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's a seperate package it depends on the OSE version. When trying to install the PUEL version (the most recent version) on Ubuntu / Debian, just add the following file for e.g. 6.0.2 @ /usr/src/vboxhost-6.0.2/dkms.conf:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="vboxhost"
PACKAGE_VERSION="6.0.2"
MAKE[0]="make"
CLEAN="make clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="vboxdrv"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[1]="vboxnetadp"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[2]="vboxnetflt"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[3]="vboxpci"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[3]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

and run `dkms autoinstall`.

Comment: I had an issue with `dkms autoinstall` so rather than running `dkms autoinstall` I ran: `dkms add -m vboxhost -v 6.0.2 && dkms build -m vboxhost -v 6.0.2 && dkms install -m vboxhost -v 6.0.2`. After that, `dkms status` listed the module and eveything worked a treat!